# Create a second contact form with redirect after submitting

Tags: forms, 6

There is a site wide contact form that's available on  https://example.com/contact. I need to add a second contact form, with some custom fields: name and suggestion.

I would also like to have a custom message after the form is submitted. Users go to https://example.com//contact/question, enter name and suggestion, submit the form, and get redirected to a page showing a thank you message.

I just need to send the form content to a specific email address.

It would be nice to avoid using any additional module.

Site is a bit old; I am afraid that installing new modules will create issues.

Comment: You can achieve this easily with webforms. Else you need to write your own code in already existing modules or where ever contact form is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to install the Webform module:

http://drupal.org/project/webform

There might be ways to do this with the Rules module, but I think for overall simplicity, Webform is the way to go.

I'm pretty sure that the version for Drupal 6 allows a custom message to be displayed to the user. In fact, if memory serves, it also has the option to redirect to a particular page.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I know that I can do custom form with webforms, but I wanted to avoid it. On the other hand writing a custom module for every form I will need is a bad idea. So probably I'll stick with webform :)